# VBScript -- Refer To Self In Program

Tags: vbscript

Is there a way to refer to the current file running in VBScript? I could just use the name of the file, but it needs to be operable despite directory changes and renames. The purpose of this is to use the file in a file I/O operation. If not possible, are there any potential alternatives, such as making a file non-re-namable, or non-movable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`WScript.ScriptFullName` gives you the full path to your running script. You can use the `FileSystemObject` to parse this path further, if you'd like. For example:

```
' Assuming the script is at c:\scripts\test.vbs
strFile = WScript.ScriptFullName

With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    MsgBox .GetDriveName(strFile)           ' => c:
    MsgBox .GetParentFolderName(strFile)    ' => c:\scripts
    MsgBox .GetFileName(strFile)            ' => test.vbs
    MsgBox .GetBaseName(strFile)            ' => test
    MsgBox .GetExtensionName(strFile)       ' => vbs    
End With
```

Comment: Don't forget `GetAbsolutePathName` because `GetParentFolderName` will NOT return the full path `C:\scripts` -> would only return `scripts`.

Comment: @Rich It does for me.

Comment: Yeah your right. vbscript framework supports complete path with GPFN. my bad, was looking at the vba version which states: "Returns a string containing the name of the parent folder of the last component in a specified path." ...so i'll go shutup now. lol sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WScript.ScriptFullName` to access the full path of the running script at run time.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Wscript.ScriptName` if you just want the script part

[This link explains in more detail](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/08/11/how-can-i-determine-the-name-of-a-script-while-that-script-is-running.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

> I could just use the name of the file, but it needs to be operable
>   despite directory changes and renames.

It is true that `Wscript.ScriptName` & `WScript.ScriptFullName` can provide detailed information on the script that is running, but if you want the code to be executed from an external I/O file that you intend on changing. You can utilize the ExecuteGlobal statement which will allow you to move `Subs` and `Functions` into the vbscript namespace.

myFunctions.vbs

```
Function GetDate()
     GetDate = DateValue(Now)
End Function
```

ExecuteInNameSpace.vbs:

```
Dim fsObj : Set fsObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim vbsFile : Set vbsFile = fsObj.OpenTextFile("myfunctions.vbs", 1, False)
Dim myFunctionsStr : myFunctionsStr = vbsFile.ReadAll
vbsFile.Close
Set vbsFile = Nothing
Set fsObj = Nothing
ExecuteGlobal myFunctionsStr
Wscript.echo "Todays Date is: " & GetDate
```

By moving all the processing of the code to an external file, you can flexibly configure and change the file all you want in your processing.